# Want to move page to show top of the news item inside update panel or how to Set Page Position after asyncPostback in AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am using a paging control on one of the pages to display news, I display about 8 items of news at one time & use Ajax Update Panel for this page to refresh only the news area, Everything works fine.  If you will visit the link you will find that if you click on the 2 page in the pager control it still remains at the bottom of the page [Example][1]

I somehow want the page to move back to top of the news items area otherwise if we have only 1 or 2 items on the second page then page looks empty & users have to use browser scroll to move up. I want pager to show the top 1st items of the news page on each page as they navigate. I cant do it in the code i am afraid. Can i some how do it using jQuery so that when ever users navigate between pages it always moves page to the 1st news item on that particular page. I hope you understand what i mean.

I need something like a bookmark so that it always moves page to 1st news item after asynchronous postback takes palce

[Link](http://www.clientsideasp.net/2010/02/01/search-engine-friendly-aspnet-digg-like-numeric-pagination-with-datalist-repeater-gridview/) for Pager control that i am using. I would appreciate help in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code helped me to set scroll position after asyncpostback

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            window.scroll(0,0);
       }
    </script>
```